# Getting a fixed visible bottom footer on a page like wappwolf

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, css

Am not great at CSS. Just want a footer that's like www.wappwolf.com - not sure how that works (CSS concepts), are there any clearly explained examples I could look at? I don't need lot of sophistication/hack job to make it work on old browsers etc. Compatibility to modern versions is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally better to at least attempt this yourself, but this should get you started:

Give your footer div these styles:

```
div{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  height:50px; //or whatever height you want
}
```

`Position Fixed` will keep the footer in the same position even when scrolling. `left and bottom` will keep it positioned at the left and bottom section of your screen (left isn't totally necessary since it's the full width of your screen but IE can sometimes be buggy without it).

Set your `height` to whatever fits your footer content the best. I assume you'll know how to set up the actual columns inside though.

Comment: Just remember to add margin to the normal content so it doesn't get hidden behind the footer.

Comment: You can also inspect your websites references to take a look at how they do ;)

Comment: `height: auto` seems to work well too, at least on modern browsers.